# How to pass parameters to procedure in MASM64?

Tags: winapi, assembly, 64-bit, parameter-passing, masm

I am learning x64 assembly with MASM64. I have read that the first 4 parameters are passed to the procedure by registers: `RCX`, `RDX`, `R9` and `R8`. If there are more parameters we pass them by stack.

But there is something confusing.

Why this code does not work:

```
sub rsp, 40h
push 0
push FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
push CREATE_ALWAYS
xor r8, r8
xor r9, r9
mov rdx, GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE
mov rcx, offset szSavePath
call CreateFileA
add rsp, 40h
```

but this code works:

```
sub rsp, 40h
mov qword ptr [rsp+30h], 0
mov qword ptr [rsp+28h], FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
mov qword ptr [rsp+20h], CREATE_ALWAYS
xor r8, r8
xor r9, r9
mov rdx, GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE
mov rcx, offset szSavePath
call CreateFileA
add rsp, 40h
```

Please help me by explaining this.
Regards, David

Comment: the 5-th parameter must be in *[rsp+20h]*, 6-th at *[rsp+28h]* and so on. also before call *rsp* must be multiple 10h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> sub rsp, 40h
> push 0
> push FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
> push CREATE_ALWAYS
> ```

Here you're putting 3 pieces of info **below** the reserved space on the stack.

```
sub rsp, 40h
mov qword ptr [rsp+30h], 0
mov qword ptr [rsp+28h], FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
mov qword ptr [rsp+20h], CREATE_ALWAYS
```

But here you're putting these data **within** the reserved space on the stack.

What happens then is that you end up with an **unbalanced stack** in the first snippet since you only release the reserved quantity using `add rsp, 40h`.

---

Same code but using pushes:

```
push 0
push FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
push CREATE_ALWAYS
sub rsp, 20h
xor r8, r8
xor r9, r9
mov rdx, GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE
mov rcx, offset szSavePath
call CreateFileA
add rsp, 20h + 18h
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there any correct way to use `push`? How to fix code using `push`?